# Jar should not point at files within the project directory? Eclipse( Maven In Build)

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

When i run Mvn clean install i am facing these errors and i am new to maven so i really dont know the meaning of this error.

Please help me to solve this error and what does it mean ?

**Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for com.sap.Hana.cloud.samples:XXXXXXX:war:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT**

**[WARNING]** 'dependencies.dependency.SystemPath' for com.sap.security.core.server:csi:jar should not point at files within the project directory, ${basedir}/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/com.sap.security.core.server.csi_1.0.1.jar will be unresolvable by dependent projects.

**[WARNING]** 'dependencies.dependency.systemPath' for com.sap.db.jdbc:ngdbc:jar should not point at files within the project directory, ${basedir}/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/ngdbc.jar will be unresolvable by dependent projects

Comment: Did you define those dependencies in the `pom.xml` with scope `system`?

Answer (score 0):

Systempath dependencies are generally a bad idea.

Instead, put the artifacts into you Nexus or Artifactory and let Jenkins resolve them.

Comment: I don't understand

Comment: From the error I strongly suspect that you have dependencies in your project which use `<systemPath>` and reference jars within the project. Don't do that.

Comment: So what should i do ? Please explain step by step

Comment: Your company has a Nexus or Artifactory, right? Then upload the artifacts to that repository and use it without  `<systemPath>`.